# How to get class of object being created in __init__ parameters

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, initialization

So I am trying to create a class with an initialization method that needs to get the type of the object being created in order to properly set the default values of the init arguments.

To give a concrete example with code, say I have the following class:

```
def __init__(self, foo, bar=type(self).some_class_variable, ham=type(self).some_other_class_variable):
        self.foo = foo
        self.bar = bar
        self.ham = self.some_function(ham)
```

This is the functionality I am looking for, but my IDE is saying `"self" is not defined` which I can understand, as `self` has yet to be instantiated. So my question is how would I go about implementing this properly? I do not want to "hardcode" the class type in where I currently have `type(self)` because subclasses of this class may have their own values for `some_class_variable` and  `some_other_class_variable` and I want those subclasses to use the class variable corresponding to their type.

My solution needs to work in Python 3.6 & Python 3.7 but I would really prefer to find a solution that works in all versions of Python 3.6 and later if possible.

Comment: Argument defaults are evaluated when the function is defined, not when it's called. `self` doesn't exist yet at definition time.

Comment: Use `bar=None` in the parameter list, and then use `if not bar: bar = type(self).some_class_variable` in the function body.

Comment: There is currently [a PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0671/) under consideration (it may or may not actually get implemented) to handle cases like this, but I agree with @Barmar that for the time being, using a sentinel like None is best.

Comment: @Barmar Okay thank you

Comment: @Dennis Good to know, thanks

Comment: Why do you need to call `type(self)`?  Instances inherit class variables, so you can just use `self.some_class_variable`

Comment: @Barmar I tried that and also saw an error stating `"self" is not defined`

Comment: In the body of the function or the argument list? The latter fails for the same reason `type(self)` fails -- the default value is evaluated when the funciton is defined, not when it's called.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry I thought you meant to do that in the function argument list I misunderstood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you should put it in the body, not the parameter.

```
def __init__(self, foo):
        self.foo = foo
        self.bar = type(self).some_class_variable
        self.ham = self.some_function(type(self).some_other_class_variable)
```

EDIT:
If the values are defaults, you can do this:

```
default_value = 'default pls'
def __init__(self, foo, bar=default_value, ham=default_value):
    self.foo = foo
    if default_value == bar: 
        self.bar = type(self).some_class_variable
    if default_value == ham: 
        self.ham = self.some_function(type(self).some_other_class_variable)
```

Comment: This solution would not work for me because it does not provide a way for the caller to supply values for bar and ham, I only wanted to create defaults in case of no caller value

Comment: @Phoenix You do that the same way you provide call-time defaults for any other parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The class name is not bound yet, as the class has not been initialised at that point. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42845972/typed-python-using-the-classes-own-type-inside-class-definition) which explains this in more depth.

A way to work-around this, albeit not that great, is to create setter methods for the variables, and to set them after an instance has been initialised, like so:

```
class Example:

    def __init__(self, foo):
        self.foo = foo
        self.bar = None
        self.ham = None

    def set_bar(self, bar):
        self.bar = bar

    def set_ham(self, ham):
        self.ham = ham
```

You can go one step further to validate the type of those attributes with a simple if statement, or through python ['typing'](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html).